# gsub to find a pattern

Tags: r, gsub

My data looks like this, and is called:  df.

```
"77 173 648 1936"
```

All the digits can have a length of 1-4 digits long.

with

```
gsub( " .*$", "", df)
#77
```

I find the 77. But how do I find the 173 in this pattern?

Comment: `strsplit(df, " ")[[1]]`?

Comment: A minor thing here: Please notice the use by @akrun of  `df1` instead of `df`. In R, `df` is a function (density for the F-distribution), and it's usually a bad idea to name variables after functions. You could try `?df`

Comment: @PavoDive, that is generally a good advice but as SO users we know that specifically "df" is very common (the most common, I would say) variable name for data in the r-tag. And in fact even while it may not be best practice, it won't mess up any code or have side effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` to extract all the numbers (`\\d+`)

```
 library(stringr)
 lapply(str_extract_all(df1, '\\d+'), as.numeric)
```

Or just

```
 scan(text=df1, sep=' ', what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
 #[1]   77  173  648 1936
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use,

```
as.numeric(regmatches(df1, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", df1))[[1]])
#[1]   77  173  648 1936
```